# Firebase data to Spinner

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

**Data trying to access**
[Firebase Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La7kd.png)

I'm trying to store all the values to a spinner but it seems like using arraylist and many other functions aren't even helping much. So, I'm just adding the code without spinner.
Final result should be to show all values in a spinner.

**SymptomActivity.java**

```
package com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class SymptomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase, spinnerDatabase;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
Button button;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_symptom);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);


    // Write a message to the database
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    // store app title to 'app_title' node
    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("app_title").setValue("microDoctor");
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("symptomList");
    spinnerDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("symptomView");
    //mFirebaseDatabase.child("Headache").child("Some Value").setValue("Head");
    //mFirebaseDatabase.setValue("Headache");


    spinnerData();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
}

private void readDataListener() {
    mFirebaseDatabase.child("Abdominal Cramps").child("Diarrhea").child("Vomiting").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Symptom symptom = dataSnapshot.getValue(Symptom.class);

            // Check for null
            if (symptom == null) {
                Log.e("Data", "Symptom data is null!");
                return;
            }

            Log.e("Symptom Data", "User data is changed!"+symptom.getDisease());

            // Display newly updated name and email
            textView.setText(symptom.symptom1+"\n"+symptom.symptom2+"\n"+symptom.symptom3+"\n"+symptom.disease+"\n"+dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to read user", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
private void spinnerData() {
    spinnerDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.e("Spinner Data", "Spinner data is changed!");

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            for (String lists : list){
                Log.d("ddd","Array List: "+dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                textView.setText(lists);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to read user", error.toException());
        }
    });

}
}
```

**content_symptom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor.SymptomActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_symptom">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="127dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="170dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method to set the data in the spinner in the following way:

```
public void showDataInSpinner(ArrayList<String> data) {
          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data
            ); //Create the Adapter to set the data
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); //Set the layout resource to create the drop down views.
            youSpinner.setAdapter(adapter); //Set the data to your spinner
    }
```

Comment: It's showing the output as:
{Uncontrollable bowel movements=Uncontrollable bowel movements, Depression=Depression} and so on.

Comment: You are not getting the value of the DataSnapshot object correctly, try with list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue (String.class)); instead.

Comment: Code is working when using the following code in onDataChange(). But I feel like this code can be cleaned now. Too much objects passing. DataSnapshot data = dataSnapshot;
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> temp = data.getChildren();
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (DataSnapshot lists : temp){
                    Log.d("ddd","Array List: "+lists.getValue().toString());
                    list.add(lists.getValue().toString());
                    textView.setText(lists.getValue().toString());
                }
                showDataInSpinner(list);

Comment: I've posted a new question for code cleaning. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212114/firebase-database-to-spinner-code-cleaning-help

Comment: Cool , if you think that i have helped you, you could select my answer as correct.