# Firebase database to Spinner [code cleaning help]

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

**Data Trying to access**

[image: Firebase Database Screenshot]

I'm trying to store all the values of database to a spinner. Final result should be to show all values in a spinner. Code is implemented somehow but I feel that there is some cleaning required in `spinnerData()` function.

**Note:** Code is fully working but the fact is that it is using too much objects and too many passing of values in `spinnerData()` and if it can be achieved with some simpler code that would be great.

**SymptomActivity.java**

```
package com.example.nishantsikri.microdoctor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class SymptomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase, spinnerDatabase;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
Button button;
TextView textView;
Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_symptom);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);


    // Write a message to the database
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    // store app title to 'app_title' node
    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("app_title").setValue("microDoctor");
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("symptomList");
    spinnerDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("symptomView");
    //mFirebaseDatabase.child("Headache").child("Some Value").setValue("Head");
    //mFirebaseDatabase.setValue("Headache");

    spinnerData();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
}

private void readDataListener() {
    mFirebaseDatabase.child("Abdominal Cramps").child("Diarrhea").child("Vomiting").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Symptom symptom = dataSnapshot.getValue(Symptom.class);

            // Check for null
            if (symptom == null) {
                Log.e("Data", "Symptom data is null!");
                return;
            }

            Log.e("Symptom Data", "User data is changed!"+symptom.getDisease());

            // Display newly updated name and email
            textView.setText(symptom.symptom1+"\n"+symptom.symptom2+"\n"+symptom.symptom3+"\n"+symptom.disease+"\n"+dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to read user", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
private void spinnerData() {
    spinnerDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.e("Spinner Data", "Spinner data is changed!");

            DataSnapshot data = dataSnapshot;
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> temp = data.getChildren();
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
//                list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
//                showDataInSpinner(list);
            for (DataSnapshot lists : temp){
                Log.d("ddd","Array List: "+lists.getValue().toString());
                list.add(lists.getValue().toString());
                textView.setText(lists.getValue().toString());
            }
            showDataInSpinner(list);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to read user", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
public void showDataInSpinner(ArrayList<String> data) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data
    ); //Create the Adapter to set the data
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); //Set the layout resource to create the drop down views.
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter); //Set the data to your spinner
}
}
```

Comment: If you're asking about restructuring code, you can check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, but there is only one thing that you need to remove. You don't need to assign the `dataSnapshot` object to a new DataSnapshot object. You can easely use `dataSnapshot` directly. So remove the new created object and use only `dataSnapshot` in your code.